# Changing the region in an API url depending on button that is active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the region in an api url depending on a button the is active.

(Example API: (region).apiurl.net)
If a person selects the button EUW, region would change to EUW, if a person selects Finland, region would change to finland.

How would I start doing this, I'm totally new to javascript and trying to learn, I tried doing this with array's or variables, but nothing worked out for me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use variables, like this:

JS code:

```
var region;
```

HTML's buttons:

```
<button onclick="region='EUW'">Western Europe</button>
<button onclick="region='Finland'">Finland</button>
```

Finally call the API from JavaSript using your variable:

```
var apiUrl = region + ".apiurl.net";
```

I hope you find this useful

Comment: Sir, you saved my life. - So It would always change variable when clicking each button right? Then I'd just need to do the active style using css?

Comment: Exactly! But you need some way of detecting which buttons is "active"

Comment: Would I do this with eventhandlers or just add a class to the first one and make the class switch with javascript when you click on other buttons?